# Android dynamic UI state inspection/profiling tool

Tags: malware, android, dynamic-analysis

I am looking after for a command-line tool that can perform dynamic view hierarchy analysis similar to the UI tool in Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.

Is there an existing tool for this? Or just some lower-level API that I can program to implement the tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out:

```
adb shell uiautomator dump
adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml path/to/output
```

or

```
adb shell uiautomator dump --compressed
adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml path/to/output
```